Redirect user to a custom redirectUrl query param after logging with Google OAuth Supabase in Next14
I'm new using Next and Supabase with OAuth, I configured my app to use server actions for signup, login, etc. It redirects correctly to "/" on local and production using these actions:
const getURL = () => {
  let url =
    process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL ??
    process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL ??
    "http://localhost:3000/";

  url = url.startsWith("http") ? url : `https://${url}`;
  url = url.endsWith("/") ? url : `${url}/`;

  return url;
};

export async function signInWithGoogle() {
  const supabase = createClient();
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: 'google',
    options: {
      redirectTo: getURL(),
    },
  });
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  if (data?.url) {
    return redirect(data.url);
  }
}

I've been trying to redirect to a redirectUrl query param but I couldn't do it:
Created URL: http://localhost:3000/auth/login?redirectUrl=%2Fgame%2F68579da9-80fb-4b1c-8556-2b93e2f59c69
options: {
  redirectTo: `${getURL()}auth/callback?redirectUrl=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl || '/')}`,
},

I did this for the email login and it worked fine:
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const redirectUrl = searchParams.get("redirectUrl");
  const [formState, action] = useFormState(login, EMPTY_FORM_STATE);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.status === "SUCCESS") {
      router.push(redirectUrl || "/");
    }
  }, [formState.status, router]);

I don't know if you have any suggestions or documentation to read, because I only found documentation for the normal redirection to /auth/callback which is still working, even when sending the redirectUrl. Thank you.
